gen baseline profile with dynamic modules
I introduced the baseline profile module based on Google Docs and generated a profile file using the Gradle task：Generate Baseline Profile.
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/create-baselineprofile?hl=zh-cn#create-new-profile
agp:8.3.2
target sdk:34
But there is a problem where the app crashes after running, making it unable to generate profile files.
The reason for the crash is the lack of XxxContentProvider class in dynamic modules.
I tried to launch the test apk directly:
Installing baselineprofile-xxx.apk and installing my app from bundle which will run normally with command installXxxBenckmark, then executing adb shell am instrument - w - e command, but encountered some mismatched exceptions and was unsuccessful.
Through build scan, it can be seen that baselineprofile: connectedXxAndroidTest depends on the packageRelease task. It should be due to a problem with the apk generated by this task, resulting in a lack of dynamic module class files.
May I ask if anyone knows of any other instructions that can handle projects containing dynamic modules? Alternatively, the correct command to start the test apk is also acceptable.
